# Using awk or sed search between multiple patterns but print only the last one matched

Tags: awk, sed

Using awk or sed how can I select lines which are occurring between two different marker patterns? There may be multiple sections marked with these patterns but want only the last one to get printed.

```
For example: Suppose the file contains:
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
mno
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
mno
pqr
stu
```

And the starting pattern is abc and ending pattern is mno So, I need the output as:

```
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

Not sure how to get this.

Comment: I didn't mean that seriously:: `tac file | sed -n '/mno/,/abc/{/mno/d;/abc/q;p}' | tac`

Comment: @Cyrus: Why not?

Comment: @userunknown: It's ugly because the whole file has to fit in memory.

Comment: most text files fit flawlessly into memory.

Comment: @GauravM: Is the length of the interesting section always the same?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/mno/{flag="";next} /abc/{val="";flag=1;next} flag{val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk '/abc/{val=""}/abc/,/mno/{if($0~/mno/||$0~/abc/){next};val=val?val ORS $0:$0}END{print val}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed '
  $bB
  :C
  /^abc$/!d
  :A
  $bB
  N
  /\nabc$/s/.*\n//
  /\nmno$/!bA
  s/[^\n]*\n\(.*\)\n[^\n]*/\1/
  h
  N
  s/.*\n//
  bC
  :B
  g
  /./!d
' infile
```